# How to access shared network folders images on angular 5 - Not allowed to load local resource

Tags: typescript, google-chrome, angular5, shared

I have accessed files within the project folder and also outside my project folder in angular 5. In this one I have been trying to load images directly from the network shared drive it does not allow me to load for some reason, So I used the [Web Server for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?hl=en) it did work when I host it with a server. and without hosting when I try to open this file on my browser it opens fine so the problem is when I try to access via angular5 I don't know why the relative path does not work in angular for a network shared drive.

To explain this well

[image]

once the user enters the user id they are able to see the results I thought a picture from the shared network drive will be better.
the path to the image would look like this
"\myfilebgds\Images\13332.jpg"
the user id also in the end would change according to the user userid

and I set this as a path to my image tag in HTML and render it accordingly.

Or if you guys can tell me a better way to access the image and show it to the user.

Comment: Try using forward slash for relative path instead of back slash..

Comment: @numbtongue when I use forward slash it makes a http get request I have no clue why ? 
also has a 404 error

Comment: Yes http access, what other did you expected.. Try putting a dot or double dot in front of it “./myfilebgds/Images/13332.jpg”.. if you use backslash you may need to escape them, provide absolute path or use current folder as a starting point, and have the right permissions..

Comment: @numbtongue That is what I tried and it still would not access it. I have no idea. I also tried to give absolute path to it. Still did not work

Comment: May be there is something like Path.Combine in Angular.. https://stackoverflow.com/q/52722655/3254405