# Is there a system-agnostic way to determine strings that represent the current and the parent directory level?

Tags: c#, mono

Different environments that C# code can be run in have different conventions/rules for what file and directory paths must look like.

A common example is the character that separates directory levels.
On Windows, it is `\`, on Linux, it is `/`, and still other (also future) systems may follow even different rules.

To create robust code, it is therefore adviseable to always use [`Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar?view=netframework-4.7.2) (or, of course, using helper methods such as [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.7.2)) rather than hard-coding a particular directory separator character.

Now, on various systems, there are some "pseudo-directory names" that can be used in paths:

- `.` represents the current directory
- `..` represents the parent directory, i.e. one level up from the current directory

While these happen to be the same on Windows and on Linux, other environments (that Mono could be implemented to run on) might follow a different syntax here.

**I do not want to hard-code these pseudo-directory names. How can I retrieve them at runtime?**

Comment: Are you talking about `Path.GetDirectoryName` or `Directory.GetParent()`?

Comment: @SeM: No. `GetDirectoryName` returns the directory portion of a path without a filename, and `GetParent` returns the parent directory of the current directory. I am talking about the strings that should be `"."` and `".."` on Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is an issue. `/` works on Windows, Unix and Linux. Same for `..` and `.`. It is also part of the *Uniform Naming Convention* that is used for network paths.

In Mono's implementation of the `Path` class `..` and `.` are even [hardcoded](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Path.cs). I don't see any sense in avoidance of hardcoding if the underlying framework even does it.

Excerpt:

```
internal static void CheckSearchPattern(String searchPattern)
{
    int index;
    while ((index = searchPattern.IndexOf("..", StringComparison.Ordinal)) != -1) {

        if (index + 2 == searchPattern.Length) // Terminal ".." . Files names cannot end in ".."
            throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Arg_InvalidSearchPattern"));

        if ((searchPattern[index+2] ==  DirectorySeparatorChar)
            || (searchPattern[index+2] == AltDirectorySeparatorChar))
            throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Arg_InvalidSearchPattern"));

        searchPattern = searchPattern.Substring(index + 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: The fact that `/` *works* on Windows doesn't help a lot if I have to parse path strings that will probably contain `\\` on Windows.

Comment: both works on windows. don't parse anything by yourself just use the Path class.

Comment: and by the way, your question is about ".." and ".", which do not change at all and are **hardcoded** in .NET/Mono